# How To Create A SetUp EXE With SQL Server 2012 in C#

Tags: c#, setuptools, setup-project

I Have Software And I Used SQL Server 2012 For Database

- I Used Entity Data Model For Connection How Can I Make SetUp With This Data Model
- I Have installShield 10.5 And advanced Installer 10.8

Comment: before ask, try to search it from documents about it on the internet.

Comment: yes i did that and nothing !